# Only have forms on the front end split

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007, I split my database (which only contains tables and forms) into front end and back end. I want my front end to only have forms, while my back end only have tables.

When I split the database, the front end has tables and forms while my back end only has tables. When I try to remove the front end tables, the front end forms don't work.

I am completely new to Access and cannot find the answer.

In the end I want to give the forms out to multiple people and not have them see what other people input into the forms and to have the information on the table in the backend.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't remove the front-end tables!  Those are really links to your back-end tables.  When you split the database, you have to leave the links in the front-end.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably have a look at using linked tables in the front end

[About importing and linking data and database objects](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx)

[MS Access: Link to a table in another database in Access 2007](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table2007.php)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I looked at the links you sent, but I don't see how to link the form on the front end with the table in the back end, without any tables in the front end.

Comment: You need to link the tables from the back-end to the front end as Linked Tables. They tehn appear in the front end under the tables section, and the front end forms should see these as if they were local tables.

Comment: I tried following: http://www.brighthub.com/link/header.aspx?u=http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932%23appliesto&p=43709&returnUrl=/computing/windows-platform/articles/43709.aspx

Comment: I tried following: http://www.brighthub.com/link/header.aspx?u=http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932%23appliesto&p=43709&returnUrl=/computing/windows-platform/articles/43709.aspx
To linking the forms to the tables, but I keep getting errors where it is asking me for the "Recordsource"

Answer (score 0):

A linked table in Microsoft Access is not actually a table that contains any data.  It is just a shortcut to a table that resides in a different database, usually called the backend.

When you split your database the front-end should contain forms, queries, macros and code modules.  And also linked tables that point to the backend database.

The backend database therefore would just contain the base tables.

Note if the backend database is moved then the linked tables will no longer work as the link would be broken.

You can either manually split your database or use the menu option built into the user interface, In Access 2007 click on database tools, then in the move data group click on access database.

To manually link tables, open your front end database and select External Data on the ribbon then click Access then after you've selected the file name make sure you select the 2nd option to link the table in the dialog box that opens.

It's a good idea to put the backend database on a server that does not get turned off and when linking avoid using mapped drives in case all users have not got the same letter mapped to the same folder share.

Comment: I got the linking to work, but the thing is that if I create 2 FE (A & B), FE A will see what FE B input in on the tables. If you are able, how do you restrict or limit what the other FE sees?